# A partial differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

EDIT: Let A and B be constants. How to solve the following partial equation system?
$$
\begin{cases}
f_x(x,y)=Ag_y(x,y)\\
f_y(x,y)=Bg_x(x,y)
\end{cases}
$$
This equation is equivalent to the equation 
$$
grad(f)=(B,A)\cdot grad(g)
$$ 
But does this help us? Thanks!

Comment: Integrate both sides of both equations with respect to the differentiation variable. Don't forget your "constants" of integration. There is no precise solution, but you can get an implicit solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I made a mistake I Edit it again.

Comment: You get $Bf_{xx}-Af_{yy}=0$ which is essentially a wave equation. Also, your equivalent equation is not equivalent, unless you make the factor on the right a matrix.

Comment: Thanks @Lutzl. How to solve a wave equation?

Comment: $u_{xx}-c^2u_{yy}=0$ in general has solutions $u(x,y)=K(y+cx)+L(y-cx)$, where the scalar functions $K,L$ are determined by the boundary conditions.